# Databases for storing and querying high frequency tick-level data?

Tags: data, database

My firm is looking for an out-of-the-box database system to store and query high-frequency tick data. What are the best options? It seems that kdb+ is the market leader in this field.

Comment: In those circumstances: The best database system is file system.

Comment: out-of-the-box? This concept does not exist in finance, unless of course you want to "trade" bitcoins. Whatever time series store you decide to go with you will not get around doing a lot of performance analytics, tweaking, and customization. Just for your reference, KDB generally sends a host of "consultants" who stay for several days just to setup the initial database structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any thing out there as a substitute for KDB?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/is-there-any-thing-out-there-as-a-substitute-for-kdb)

Comment: I'm also quite interested in this; if anyone knows of a free DB that integrates well with .NET, please do tell.

Comment: not aware of such free product. if low frequency, check open-tsdb.

Comment: @Arman, check out Teafiles, also consider writing your own binary data store, or you could consider document DBs, but other than that there are not a whole lot of open-source columnar DBs out there.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is the [TeaFiles file format](https://teafiles.codeplex.com/). It's simple and boasts a high performance but I believe you'll have to reinvent some wheels.

Comment: By the way: this is almost a duplicate of http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/is-there-any-thing-out-there-as-a-substitute-for-kdb/3209#3209

Comment: ups, just saw your answer, also recommended it in my comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

kdb+ seems to be the leader but their programming language is a pain really. Personally I use a HDF5. It is a No-SQL database. It integrates very nicely with python.

I have been very happy with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

velocity analytics might be a choice.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about why?

Comment: you may check http://thomsonreuters.com/enterprise-platform-velocity-analytics/

Comment: @DanielQin you should ellaborate in your answer, otherwise, please just post a comment. This is one of the good practices of this web site. Thanks. And welcome anyway.